# Converting project to SQL Server, design thoughts?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclr

Currently, I'm sitting on an ugly business application written in Access that takes a spreadsheet on a bi-daily basis and imports it into a MDB.  I am currently converting a major project that includes this into SQL Server and .net, specifically in c#.

To house this information there are two tables (alias names here) that I will call Master_Prod and Master_Sheet joined on an identity key parent to the Master_Prod table, ProdID.  There are also two more tables to store history, History_Prod and History_Sheet.  There are more tables that extend off of Master_Prod but keeping this limited to two tables for explanation purposes.

Since this was written in Access, the subroutine to handle this file is littered with manually coded triggers to deal with history that were and have been a constant pain to keep up with, one reason why I'm glad this is moving to a database server rather than a RAD tool.  I am writing triggers to handle history tracking.

My plan is/was to create an object modeling the spreadsheet, parse the data into it and use LINQ to do some checks client side before sending the data to the server... Basically I need to compare the data in the sheet to a matching record (Unless none exist, then its new).  If any of the fields have been altered I want to send the update.

Originally I was hoping to put this procedure into some sort of CLR assembly that accepts an IEnumerable list since I'll have the spreadsheet in this form already but I've recently learned this is going to be paired with a rather important database server that I am very concerned with bogging down.

Is this worth putting a CLR stored procedure in for?  There are other points of entry where data enters and if I could build a procedure to handle them given the objects passed in then I could take a lot of business rule away from the application at the expense of potential database performance.

Basically I want to take the update checking away from the client and put it on the database so the data system manages whether or not the table should be updated so the history trigger can fire off.

Thoughts on a better way to implement this along the same direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx). Use [Excel Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx) to read the spreadsheets, perhaps use a [Lookup Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx) to detect new items and finally use a [SQL Server Destination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141095.aspx) to insert the stream of missing items into SQL.

SSIS is *way* better fit to these kind of jobs that writing something from scratch, no matter how much fun linq is. SSIS Packages are easier to debug, maintain and refactor than some dll with forgoten sources. Besides, you will not be able to match the refinements SSIS has in managing its buffers for high troughput [Data Flows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140080.aspx).

Comment: Wow... I havn't been given access to a tool such as this but need to ask if I can get it.  This would do wonders for many other import processes we currently handle through irritating custom maintained functions here and there

Answer (score 2):

> Originally I was hoping to put this
>   procedure into some sort of CLR
>   assembly that accepts an IEnumerable
>   list since I'll have the spreadsheet
>   in this form already but I've recently
>   learned this is going to be paired
>   with a rather important database
>   server that I am very concerned with
>   bogging down.

Does not work. Any input into a C# written CLR procedure STILL has to follow normal SQL semantics. All that can change is the internal setup. Any communication up with the client has to be done in SQL. Which means executions / method calls. No way to directly pass in an enumerable of objects.

Answer (score 1):

> My plan is/was to create an object
>   modeling the spreadsheet, parse the
>   data into it and use LINQ to do some
>   checks client side before sending the
>   data to the server... Basically I need
>   to compare the data in the sheet to a
>   matching record (Unless none exist,
>   then its new). If any of the fields
>   have been altered I want to send the
>   update.

You probably need to pick a "centricity" for your approach - i.e. data-centric or object-centric.

I would probably model the data appropriately first.  This is because relational databases (or even non-normalized models represented in relational databases) will often outlive client tools/libraries applications.  I would probably start trying to model in a normal form and think about the triggers to maintain audit/history as you mention during this time also.

I would typically then think of the data coming in (not an object model or an entity, really).  So then I focus on the format and semantics of the inputs and see if there is misfit in my data model - perhaps there were assumptions in my data model which were incorrect.  Yes, I'm not thinking of making an object model which validates the spreadsheet even though spreadsheets are notoriously fickle input sources.  Like Remus, I would simply use SSIS to bring it in - perhaps to a staging table and then some more validation before applying it to production tables with some T-SQL.

Then I would think about a client tool which had an object model based on my good solid data model.

Alternatively, the object approach would mean modeling the spreadsheet, but also an object model which needs to be persisted to the database - and perhaps you now have two object models (spreadsheet and full business domain) and database model (storage persistence), if the spreadsheet object model is not as complete as the system's business domain object model.

I can think of an example where I had a throwaway external object model kind of like this.  It read a "master file" which was a layout file describing an input file.  This object model allowed the program to build SSIS packages (and BCP and SQL scripts) to import/export/do other operations on these files.  Effectively it was a throwaway object model - it was not used as the actual model for the data in the rows or any kind of navigation between parent and child rows, etc., but simply an internal representation for internal purposes - it didn't necessarily correspond to a "domain" entity.